# Stop power-off during lockscreen

Tags: gnome, 20.04, power-management

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64.
When I go to bed, I want to lock the screen and have backups run in the middle of the night.
However, when I get to the computer in the morning, it has powered off/suspended. I do NOT want it to power off/suspend, because backups cannot happen.

- Settings->Power does not have an option for powering off when the computer is inactive.
- Automatic Suspend is set to "When on battery power". My computer is not on battery power when this happens.

The following settings are in force: (Note that sleep-inactive-ac-type is set to 'nothing', which should do nothing when the timeout is reached.)

```
% gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power 
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 3600
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 1800
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 120
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

Comment: "Powered off" or "Suspended"? They're vastly different system states.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`,  check my AskUbuntu profile (click on my userid), there are `journalctl` and `date` command hints. Check the logs, using the `--since=` and `--until` options to `journalctl`.

Comment: I think it's Suspend. My computer is powered off in the morning. I can press the power button, and I get the login prompt and my session is restored after logging in.

Comment: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, regular PC no battery, use it as an email server among other things, but it suspends when left on the login screen. Weird thing is `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` shows `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 0`, but `gsettings get com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout` outputs 1200. When logged in as my regular user then `su -` to get root.